# Need help on rewriting a query that Uses a Cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cursor, user-defined-functions

I have a query that looks like this:

```
DECLARE Match_Cursor CURSOR
FOR
   SELECT ID,UserKey,TypeCode
   FROM [DB1].Table1 as t1
OPEN Match_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Match_cursor INTO @ID,@UserKey,@TypeCode;
   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO #TempTable
          SELECT  t2.Name, t2.Address, t2.Country, @UserKey, @TypeCode
          FROM  [DB1].[DBO].udf_TableFunction(@ID) as t2
          where @typeCode = 142 AND t2.Country = 'US'
FETCH NEXT FROM Match_cursor INTO @ID,@UserKey,@TypeCode;
   END

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

Does anyone have suggestions for rewriting this using joins?  Assume there is a foreign key relation ship between `t1.ID` and `t2.ID`.

Comment: What does udf_TableFunction return?   The problem is that it returns a single row.   Could it be adapted to return all rows (say if ID is NULL), in which case you could join against it...

Comment: It returns a collection of rows.  It can't be changed to return all rows if null is passed in, but null will never be passed.

Comment: Need to see `udf_TableFunction` contents

Comment: If all udf_tablefunction does is return the ID, name, address, country from a table, why not simply reference the underlying table?   I agree with OMG Ponies, it is kind of tough to recommend anything without know what the function is doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`cross apply`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) to pass `Table1.ID` to `udf_TableFunction`.

Here is a pseudo code on how you might go about to do so.
(I don't have access to SSMS right now so couldn't test it)

```
insert #TempTable(...)
select ...
from  table1 t1 cross apply [DBO].udf_TableFunction(t1.ID) t2
where ...
```

Comment: Ended up breaking the table functions into the original query and using cross apply.